# Android Application onCreate() and Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Tags: android, android-intent, singleton

Simple question as it seems, I can't figure out the answer.
Is it possible that `onCreate()` of Application singleton class will **not** be triggered on Application Update?

(Update may be via the Android Studio with version upgrade)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
But it's very likely that when using Android Studio you install the APK without upgrade the  app version in your gradle so the `broadcast` is never being send.

Comment: No, I always upgrade the version. Definitely no?

Comment: I haven't found official documentation to support my answer but as far as I know an experienced, definitely no.I would recommend to create that broadcast via ADB to verify your assumptions.